# Angular 4: Table with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I'm trying to create a dynamic table with angular 4, but I'm not allowed to use *ngFor with a tr? Any idea how to solve this?

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm m-0">
  <thead class="">
  <tr>
    <th>FirstName</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Registration Date</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>E-mail address</th>
    <th>Role</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody >
  <tr *ngFor="user in users">
    <td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
    <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
    <td>{{user.registrationDate}}</td>
    <td>{{user.phoneNumber}}</td>
    <td>{{user.email}}</td>
    <td>{{user.userRole}}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The exact error is:

> compiler.es5.js:1690 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind
>   to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'. ("
>         
>         
>         ]*ngFor="user in users">
>           {{user.firstName}}
>           {{user.lastName}} "): ng:///AppModule/UserListComponent.html@15:10 Can't bind to 'ngForIn'
>   since it isn't a known property of 'tr'. ("

Comment: *ngFor syntax is wrong, try this <tr *ngFor="let user of users">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `ngFor` is wrong as the `ngForIn` is deprecated([refer docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgFor))

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users">
    <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
</tr>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/OjVbsqW17OfdNFaCC9m8?p=preview)**

Comment: happy to help you. :) :)

Answer (score 0):

In the new syntax of angular you need to declare the local variable for structural directives.
so use,

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users">
    <td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
    <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
    <td>{{user.registrationDate}}</td>
    <td>{{user.phoneNumber}}</td>
    <td>{{user.email}}</td>
    <td>{{user.userRole}}</td>
  </tr>
```

The let keyword declares a template input variable that you reference within the template.

Comment: It should be "let user of users" and not "let user in users"